# How do I add a fixed value property to my model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-design, asp.net-mvc-4

Suppose I have a Task model:

```
public class Task()
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public int Title {get;set;}
}
```

Now I want to add a *'repeat'* property.

The property can only hold one of 3 values:

1. Daily
2. Weekly
3. Monthly

Do I create a RepeatOption() model and add its foreign key to the Task() model -- or is there a more optimal solution, maybe use an enum? (just guessing here)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is something hard-coded that is unlikely to change, I'd just use an enum type with those three values.

Comment: How would such an enum property look in the Task() model (using Entity Framework)

Comment: @user2312633: Entity Framework now supports enum values, so you could actually tell Entity Framework that the property should be of your `enum` type, and it will take care of translating it to and from the underlying SQL integer value.

Answer (score 2):

```
public enum RepeatOption
{
    Daily,
    Weekly,
    Monthly
}

public class Task()
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public int Title {get;set;}
   public RepeatOption Repeat {get;set;}
}
```

In DB field `Repeat` should be store as `int`, unless you some specififc requirements for it.